# What gets captured in SiteSection by default?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a scenarios where I want to to understand the default values captured in the SiteSection. I am not looking to populate any  values in the sitesection but I still want to use it. Wondering what gets captured in the Site Section in Adobe analytics if I do not populate the s.channel  variable.

Will it capture the page name? or will it follow the website structure i.e. the directory hierarchy?

I haven't tried it yet. this was a question that I was asked, however due to the paid nature of Adobe Analytics I am not able to test this

Comment: AA library does not populate `s.channel` with a default value, so if you don't set it, you will see "unspecified" or "none" (depending on report/context) if you don't populate it. In practice, I see most people populate it with the first directory/folder in the URL path, e.g. `s.channel=location.pathname.split('/')[0];`  (assuming your site URL structure is friendly for that paradigm). This would be populated in your page code (e.g. set it in Adobe Launch if you are using that to deploy AA). Alternatively, you can set it in a Processing Rule within the AA interface.